# Accessing iSCSI LUN from OS X and Debian simultaneously

Tags: debian, mac-osx, filesystems, storage-area-network, iscsi

My setup is the following:

```
Synology Disk Station as iSCSI target
OS X 10.8 as client
Debian as client
```

I don't like to know that I should use WebDAV or similar file sharing protocols.

I'd like to access the same target from at least the both above named devices. What file system should I use? I guess it should be a cluster file system, but which one should I use for best compatibility?

Comment: And why not WEBDAV or NFS ? They work well and is compatible with both platforms, without the weight of a clustered filesystem ? Why don't you be able to use NAS ?

Comment: Because WebDAV sucks?

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to simultaniously access the LUN from both debian and OS X you'll need a clustered filesystem like GFS.

This means that you'd have to cluster your OS X with the debian box, and that sounds to me like a really bad idea. I doubt if it's even doable.

Since your Synology Disk Station is a single point of failure already, clustering the file system will not save you from problems, but is likely to introduce them instead.

You'll save yourself a lot of headache by accessing the files through something like NFS.